# How to get a subtotal and total price ? Laravel foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have this code right here:

```
@foreach($products as $p)
<tr>
    <td class="col-md-6">
        <div class="media">
            <a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#"> <img class="media-object" src="{{URL::to($p['image'])}}" style="width: 72px; height: 72px;"> </a>
            <div class="media-body">
                <span style="padding-left: 20px">Pavadinimas: </span><span class="text-warning"><strong>{{$p['title']}}</strong></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" value="{{$p['quantity']}}">
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-1 text-center">
        <strong>{{$p['price']}} EUR</strong>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-1 text-center">
        <strong>{{$p['price']*$p['quantity']}} EUR</strong>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Pašalinti
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

the `$products` is in foreach loop and I don't know how to get the all price if there're two, three or more products because I don't know how to set variable outside foreach loop. Because if I add this code in foreach loop wich is not right now added in foreach loop:

```
<tr>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td><h5>Subtotal</h5></td>
    <td class="text-right"><h5><strong> EUR</strong></h5></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td><h5>Another taxes</h5></td>
    <td class="text-right"><h5><strong>1.44 EUR</strong></h5></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td><h3>Total</h3></td>
    <td class="text-right"><h3><strong> EUR</strong></h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Žiūrėti kitas prekes
        </button>
    </td>
    <td>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Užsakyti 
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
       </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This code will just duplicate. So any suggestion how to get total price of all products in cart without adding this piece of code in foreach loop ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying the get the total of the $products collection, then try `{{ $products->sum('amount'); }}`

Alternatively, you could use JavaScript to dynamically update the total. If that value is then needed to be passed into a controller on form::submit, then you could store the value in a hidden input.

Comment: How about quantities? how should I do if I sum together with the quantities?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand the question?